# Where did my money go? will I get it still?

Tags: transfer

I went to transfer money from my bio life card to my bank account online, I accidentally put in my 16 digit debit card number instead of my account number will my money still go to my checking account? I dont know where the money went to, I provided the right routing number, what will happen

Comment: If there's a valid account associated with that routing number, then it will likely go to that account, if not, probably the transfer will fail to go through. Better contact support.

Comment: Which Country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

If the debit card is associated with the account, there is nowhere else it could go. The chance is nil that there is another account with that 16-digit number.

So either it goes there, or the transfer fails and it is right back where it came from, though this could take some days. If you don't want to risk a wait, talk to your bank now.

Comment: Talk to your bank _now_ in any case. If the money will end up in the right place, or bounce back, it won't matter. If it _is_ headed somewhere else, you may be able to stop/reverse it in time.